# Node.js won't run localhost, dependency issues with webpack-dev-server and cardkit

Tags: node.js, macos, yeoman-generator

[Console message when I run the npm start command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppb6Z.png)

[npm audit security report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Jbd.png)

Comment: Those aren't error messages.

Comment: Please post your error messages here instead of a link. Also, use text instead of images where possible

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to node.  I have gone through the documentation not sure where I need to go to install the peer dependencies.

Comment: $ npm start

> test-1-repo-cardkit-project@1.0.0 start /Users/richard.biesty/cardkit-project
> node src/app.js

Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated, and will be removed in  React v16.0. Use the latest available v15.* prop-types package from npm instead.